# custom delegation from child class to parent class (subview-superview)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to send data from a child class to a parent class. after implementing my custom delegation, I received this error:

```
 Cannot find protocol declaration for 'SLBPostViewControllerDelegate'
```

Here is my code:

**child.h**

```
@protocol SLBPostViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)dataToBeUploaded:(PFFile *)data;

@end

@interface

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SLBPostViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**child.m**

```
[self.delegate dataToBeUploaded:image];
```

**parent.h**

```
@interface SLBWallViewController : UIViewController <SLBPostViewControllerDelegate>
```

**parent.m**

```
- (void)dataToBeUploaded:(PFFile *)data{
    NSLog(@"%@", data);
}
```

Where is my mistakes? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`parent.h` needs to `#import child.h` in order to know about the protocol declaration.

If you are importing it and still getting the error, it is possible that circular imports exist. In that case, forward declare the protocol in `parent.h` above the `@interface` like

```
@protocol SLBPostViewControllerDelegate;

@interface SLBWallViewController : UIViewController <SLBPostViewControllerDelegate>
...
@end
```